# How to create common custom toolbar(any other element) in all pages by importing that particular component in ionic 2 RC0 version?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have attached the custom toolbar as image. I have attached the code that I am trying to work on it.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {IONIC_DIRECTIVES} from 'ionic/ionic';
@Component({
  selector: 'slime-toolbar',
  templateUrl: 'slime-toolbar.html',
  directives: [IONIC_DIRECTIVES]
})
```

But the above code gives error, that directives can not be argument for the component

[image]

Comment: In Angular2 (I think this is the same in Ionic2), Component decoration has not "directives" attribute. Insert directives in module, in "declarations" or "imports" attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest creating a custom component derived from the ion-header instead. 
Although you dont mention what functionality you want in your custom toolbar it can be assumed that you want to change the style and items that are added based on logic from certain pages. ie. you want to pass a title string  depending on what page you are on or add an icon to the right etc.

**Styling**

Styling is fairly straight forward. If you want a style your component across the application then the best solution is to target the ionic 2 variables which can be found [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/) . For example if you want to change the background color you can just edit the `src` -> `theme` -> `variables.scss` file like so

```
$toolbar-ios-background:(green);
$toolbar-md-background:(green);
```

There are various other toolbar specific variables that can easily be adjusted.
If you want to change the style based on the page the user is on then it will be added as an attribute in the `<ion-header>` explained further on as an input.

**Component**

First off i would use the cli to quickly generate a component

```
 $: ionic g component my-header
```

And then add that component to the `app.module.ts` as a declaration.

```
import { MyHeaderComponent } from '../components/myheader/myheader';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
     MyApp,
     Page1,
     Page2,
     MyHeaderComponent
],
```

You can then change the components html to

```
<ion-header no-border>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
     <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
   </button>
   <ion-title>{{text}}</ion-title>
 </ion-navbar>
```

And add the newly create header component where you would normally have the `<ion-header>` full html, normally on the top of you page before the `<ion-content>` tag on the page you want it to be displayed. This will now display your custom component as a ionic 2 header element. But the main customization happens when you add the `@Input()` and `@Output()` to your components `.ts`

**The Custom Bit**

Add to your components `.ts`

```
import { Component,Input,Output,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
```

Now you can use the Input

```
@Input('headerText') dynamicHeaderText;
text:string;
```

`headerText` is the name of the attribute you add to your custom component

```
<my-header headerText="New title"></my-header>
```

`New title` is the string that will be passed into the component and be assigned to `dynamicHeaderText`

You can then assign the `dynamicHeaderText` to the `text:string`

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.text = this.dynamicHeaderText;
}
```

So now the added string ( New Title ) in the custom component tag (which can be created as custom logic based on the page that it is on ) is passed to your custom components logic into the variable `dynamicHeaderText` which can then be manipulated and assigned to the variable that is added on the custom components html.

There is a lot more you can do and would suggested looking further into custom components to add dynamic logic for snippets of code. 
Note if you add a dynamic value your need to change you attribute to include square brackets.

```
<my-header [headerText]="dynamicLogicText"></my-header>
```

So now you get all the good stuff from the ionic 2 header and a package of reusable code based on your own custom logic. Which makes testing and maintainability a lot easier.

hope that makes sense.

Comment: @SESN upated the answer

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I have implemented using ViewChild decorator.